# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php

Currently I am getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''&i='' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/some/thing/index.php on line 45

which is the line below:

```
$content = '<iframe width="100%" height="70" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="http://example.com/player/audio.php?mp3=http://www.example.com/mp3embed-'.$secret.'.mp3''&i='.$row['image'].'&s='.$songz.'&a='.$artistz.'"></iframe>';
```

I am not completely sure what I am doing wrong here but I feel like what ever it is sort of indicates that i'm a goofy goober.

Comment: `.mp3''&i` should be `.mp3&i`, can't have quotes like that.

Comment: You could use double quotes for the string encapsulation and then single quotes for the HTML attribute encapsulation. This way you won't need the concatenation because the variables can be in the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$content = '<iframe width="100%" height="70" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="http://example.com/player/audio.php?mp3=http://www.example.com/mp3embed-'.$secret.'.mp3''&i='.$row['image'].'&s='.$songz.'&a='.$artistz.'"></iframe>';
```

To:

```
$content = '<iframe width="100%" height="70" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="http://example.com/player/audio.php?mp3=http://www.example.com/mp3embed-'.$secret.'.mp3&i='.$row['image'].'&s='.$songz.'&a='.$artistz.'"></iframe>';
```

You can't just end and start a string like that without some sort of concatenation in between.

Comment: Thanks man for not laughing at me for being a noob and helping me out so quickly!

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Ty changing

```
$content = '<iframe width="100%" height="70" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="http://example.com/player/audio.php?mp3=http://www.example.com/mp3embed-'.$secret.'.mp3''&i='.$row['image'].'&s='.$songz.'&a='.$artistz.'"></iframe>';
```

to

```
$content = '<iframe width="100%" height="70" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="http://example.com/player/audio.php?mp3=http://www.example.com/mp3embed-'.$secret.'.mp3&i='.$row['image'].'&s='.$songz.'&a='.$artistz.'"></iframe>';
```